# ProviderNotFoundException Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-bloc

in the text field i am trying to use context.read but i get this error ProviderNotFoundException and i think the route is correct but i don't know why it is happening .
i am trying to use the textfield data to change something in my items list .
would you please help me with my code i would appreciate .
This is my code

```
body: BlocProvider<TaskListBloc>(
        create: (context) => TaskListBloc(context.read<Repository<TaskEntity>>()),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 120,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        end: Alignment.centerRight,
                        colors: [
                      themeData.colorScheme.primary,
                      themeData.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                    ])),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                  child: Column(children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'To Do List',
                          style: themeData.textTheme.titleLarge,
                        ),
                        const Icon(CupertinoIcons.share)
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 16,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 38,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(19),
                          color: themeData.colorScheme.background,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                                blurRadius: 20)
                          ]),
                      child: TextField(
                          controller: controller,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                           context.read<TaskListBloc>().add(TaskListSearch(value));
                          },
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              label: Text('Search Task'),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.search))),
                    )
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Consumer<Repository<TaskEntity>>(
                  builder: (context, model, child) {
                    context.read<TaskListBloc>().add(TaskListStarted());
                    return BlocBuilder<TaskListBloc , TaskListState>(builder: (context, state) {
                    if(state is TaskListSuccess){
                      return TaskList(items: state.items, themeData: themeData);
                    }else if(state is TaskListEmpty){
                      return const EmptyState();
                    }else if (state is TaskListLoading || state is TaskListInitial){
                          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                    }else if(state is TaskListError){
                      return Center(child: Text(state.errorMessage),);
                    }else{
                      throw Exception('State is Not Valid');
                    }
                      
                  },);
                  },
                )
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the code does not find which is the parent `context` that contains the creation of your Bloc. So after you have created your **BlocProvider**, you should put the following :

```dart
body: BlocProvider<TaskListBloc>(
        create: (context) =>
            TaskListBloc(context.read<Repository<TaskEntity>>()),
        child: Builder( // HERE
          builder: (context) {
            return SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                children: [
              
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        ),
      ),
```

You have to create the Widget Builder where you bring the context with the Bloc